# Does SQL Server 2005 use short-circuit evaluation in constraints?

Tags: sql-server-2005

If I have that constraint on a table,

```
 (field1 is null and field2 is not null and dbo.expensivefunction(field2) = field3)
```

If my field2 is null, is the function will be called anyway?

Is "and" equal the meaning of (andalso, &&) in .Net in a constraint on sql server 2005?

Comment: Your title does not appear to match your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does short circuit operations, but the order of the operations depends on the optimizer so the answer is maybe.  See this [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/isaac/archive/2008/05/07/evaluation-order.aspx).   In practice, I've used statements such as yours without problems -- probably because the optimizer puts the simpler checks first, though there isn't a guarantee.

Comment: thanks for giving me the expression "short circuit evaluation" I didn't know how to call that